# How to get weights from a layer subclass defined inside a layer.layers class in Tensorflow?

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, deep-learning, tensorflow2.0

I have the code below, where inside the convProjection class, I defined a Conv1D layer from keras.
I want to get the weights of the Conv1D defined. Although since it's not initalized, getting the weights with `self.Projection.get_weights()` returns an empty array. I tried to initalize it manually inside call but it doesn't seem to work. How can I get the weights of the Conv1D layer in this case? I will also need to set them back after manipulating them.

```
kernelSize = 32
stride = 16
class convProjections(layers.Layer):
    def __init__(self, kernelSize,stride):
        super(convProjections, self).__init__()
        self.Projection = layers.Conv1D(filters = projection_dim,kernel_size = kernelSize,strides = stride)
    def call(self, inputData):
        Projections = self.Projection(inputData)
        convWeights = self.Projection.get_weights()
        ####I will do some something here with convWeights####

        return Projections

def model
    inputs = layers.Input(shape=input_shape)
    patches = convProjections(kernelSize,stride)(inputs)
    logits = layers.Dense(8,  activation='softmax')(patches )
    model = keras.Model(inputs=inputs, outputs=logits)
```

Preferably, I'd like to stick with Model subclassing to define my model. But is open to solutions

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to build your `convProjections` properly. You have to create the layer weights in the `build(self, inputs_shape)` method of your layer. Then you have to use these weights in the `call` method to operate convolution using `tf.nn.conv1d`. In the end of `call` you can do whatever you want with `self.convWeights`.

```
class convProjections(layers.Layer):

    def __init__(self, projection_dim, kernelSize, stride, use_bias=True):
        super(convProjections, self).__init__()
        self.projection_dim = projection_dim
        self.kernelSize = kernelSize
        self.stride = stride
        self.use_bias = use_bias

    def build(self, input_shape):
        self.convWeights = self.add_weight(
            shape=(self.kernelSize, input_shape[-1], self.projection_dim),
            initializer="random_normal",
            trainable=True,
        )
        if self.use_bias:
            self.convBias = self.add_weight(
                shape=(self.projection_dim,), initializer="random_normal", trainable=True
            )

    def call(self, inputData):

        conv = tf.nn.conv1d(
            inputData, 
            filters=self.convWeights, 
            stride=[1,self.stride,1], 
            padding='SAME',
            data_format='NWC'
        )

        if self.use_bias:
            conv = tf.nn.bias_add(conv, self.convBias)

        ### DO SOMETHING WITH self.convWeights ###

        print(self.convWeights.shape)

        return conv
```

Building the model:

```
input_shape = (24,6)
kernelSize = 32
stride = 1
projection_dim = 64

inputs = layers.Input(shape=input_shape)
patches = convProjections(projection_dim,kernelSize,stride)(inputs)
outputs = layers.Dense(8,  activation='softmax')(patches)
model = Model(inputs=inputs, outputs=outputs)
```